# Excel Power Pivot Relationships

Tags: excel, relationship, dax, powerpivot

i have 2 tables as the below pic
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1YbG.jpg)

and i created relationship between 2 tables in power pivot as the below pic
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q39mp.jpg)

then i created pivot table and inserted [Project] & [Phase] in rows Area as the below pic
[Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufGTW.jpg)

the question : why the all [Phase] Column show under Each Project not only items related to each project ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because until a measure/aggregation has been added
in the Values area PivotTable do not build the relationship and
the initial state is unique value combination from the two tables.

Thanks